# Should the EF5 dll be compiled against the v4.0.30319 .NET runtime?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a .NET 4.5 ASP.NET MVC project in VS2012. I use EF5. When I install it I notice that the .NET runtime that it is compiled against is v4.0.30319. Is this a problem? I was expecting to see V4.5?

I have unistalled it and reinstalled using Package Manager Console, but to no avail, still showing the .NET v4.0.30319 version. Perhaps it is meant to be like this? Just asking as I am having some precompile issues, and wanted to check this out as a possible cause.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4,5 runtime is an inplace update of 4,0, so that is the correct version, yes.

Comment: Thanks, most appreciated. So v4.0.30319 should show as the "Runtime Version" in properties in VS?